# Docker Windows DNS failing

Tags: docker, dns

I'm seeing many DNS issues on my Docker CE for Windows:

```
$ docker run -it --rm busybox
Unable to find image 'busybox:latest' locally
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:34504->[::1]:53: read: connection refused.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
```

Also when trying to build an image:

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
```

Where can I check on Docker for network settings/log as this looks like a docker related issue? I can resolve fine on my host machine.

Comment: Is this using the Hyper-V docker VM?

Comment: yes - in linux container mode

Comment: So in most probable case the internet is not reaching inside the VM or DNS is not working. Do you have a custom DNS server in some office network?